# Premium bonds prize probabilities

Tags: multinomial-distribution

The UK have an initiative called [Premium Bonds](https://www.nsandi.com/products/premium-bonds). You can buy a £1 bond, and each month there is a 1 in 24,000 chance of winning a cash prize from that bond. The number of prizes given per month for each amount, for all bonds that have been bought, is below (from which you can calculate the probability of your prize being a particular amount):

```
Prize       Number won
£1,000,000  2
£100,000    56
£50,000     112
£25,000     223
£10,000     559
£5,000      1,118
£1,000      11,983
£500        35,949
£100        1,160,883
£50         1,160,883
£25         2,621,112
```

So, you can calculate the probability of winning any particular prize on a given month from 1 bond, by multiplying 1/24,000 by the conditional probability of winning that prize, given that you won a prize.

The probability of winning nothing is just 1 minus the sum of all the won-prize probabilities.

You can buy multiple bonds, up to a maximum of 50,000, and each month the prize odds are rolled for each bond you own, independently. So you could win multiple prizes from different bonds, and the amount you win in the month could be anywhere upwards from £25 - e.g. last month I won £25 from 4 bonds, so £100 total.

I would like to produce a function that can provide the probability of winning at least a certain amount *y* in a month (from multiple combinations of amounts), from a given number of premium bonds that you own *x*. I guess *y* could go up in increments of £25, if necessary, seeing as that's the minimum prize value.

I think this is some kind of multinomial distribution maybe, so maybe there's a formula that could be used there...? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You could address this with generating functions, though it would not give a closed form in general.  You might start by noting that in the month you highlight, there were $4\, 992\, 880$ prizes and presumably about $24000$ times as many £1 bonds outstanding

Comment: I cannot find a way to compute any probabilities from these numbers.  They seem to say nearly £300,000,000 is awarded monthly, corresponding to an incredible 120 billion pound monthly investment; and that doesn't give us information about the number of bonds not winning anything.

Comment: @whuber $\frac{23999}{24000}$ of bonds do not win a particular month.   https://inews.co.uk/news/consumer/premium-bonds-winners-october-2022-winning-ns-and-i-checker-have-won-1890431 says "119,340,101,225 eligible numbers" in September 2022, though this changes slowly each month, so your £120 billion looks close enough - it is part of the funding of the UK national debt.  Remember that you never lose your stake, and the expected prizes are now designed to be equivalent to [interest of about $3\%$ a year](https://www.nsandi.com/interest-rates), though this varies over time

Comment: A slight issue is that this is not multinomial but instead multivariate hypergeometric; you cannot win the three of the million pound prizes in a single month, no matter how lucky you are or how many bonds you hold.  There will be good approximations, and simulation is always an option.

Comment: @Henry I still cannot determine the probabilities from this information.

Comment: @whuber why not?  For the quoted month (January 2023, so it has not happened yet and may be adjusted marginally when they know how many bonds are in the draw),  a £1 individual bond seems to be expected to have probability $\frac{119824127120}{119829120000}$ of not winning anything, $\frac{2621112}{119829120000}$ of winning £25, and so on down to $\frac{2}{119829120000}$ of winning £1million.  The probability of somebody with £50000 worth of bonds (the maximum allowed) of winning nothing is $\frac{{119824127120 \choose 50000}}{{119829120000 \choose 50000}} \approx 0.1245$ and others similarly

Comment: I think @Henry is correct. I should have said, the numbers up there are the *expected* number prizes to be given in Jan 2023, which I suppose are drawn directly from their probabilities. Will try a simulation actually, that sounds like a good idea!

Comment: @Henry What is the chance of not winning anything?  Is that exactly 23999/24000, so that the chances you compute are the conditional probabilities of prizes?

Comment: @whuber Marginal not conditional.The chance of an individual bond not winning anything in a particular month is designed to be exactly $\frac{23999}{24000}$, or at least as close to that as possible - the number of bonds is unknown in advance and may not be an exact multiple of $24000$ in a particular month: as well as that, the actual prize distribution is decided at the beginning of the month so the the expected total value of the prizes (in January 2023) is $1.03^{1/12}-1$ times the number of bonds; then the draw selects the appropriate number of prize-winning bonds (without replacement).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the number of £1 bonds entered into the January 2023 draw was 119,680,941,890 rather than the predicted 119,829,120,000 so the [numbers of prizes were adjusted very slightly](https://nsandi-corporate.com/news-research/news/new-year-joy-two-premium-bonds-millionaires-south-yorkshire-and-wiltshire) to keep the probability of a particular bond winning as close as possible to $\frac1{24000}$ and the total value of the prizes as close as possible to $0.25\%$ of the total value of bonds entered.  But since I personally won about $2.6$ times my expected winnings this month, I thought I would come back to this question.

It seems that the selection of prizes without replacement makes the calculations difficult, but assuming they are with replacement makes very little difference expect to the relative error of the probability of winning very large amounts.  The absolute  errors are small everywhere, for example for someone with the maximum holding of £50,000 of bonds (not me), the actual probability of no prizes without replacement was

```
dhyper(0, 4986706, 119680941890 - 4986706, 50000) 
# 0.124509008
```

while assuming replacement would give

```
dbinom(0, 50000, 4986706 / 119680941890)
# 0.124509063
```

almost the same value.

It is certainly possible to simulate without replacement, perhaps along the following lines, though it will not be particularly precise:

```
#Premium Bonds simulation # January 2023
prizevalue <- c(1000000, 100000, 50000, 25000, 10000, 
                5000, 1000, 500, 100, 50, 25)
prizenumber <- c(2, 56, 111, 224, 559, 
                 1116, 11968, 35904, 1159432, 1159432, 2617902)
totalbonds <- 119680941890
numberprizes <- sum(prizenumbers) 
onein <- totalbonds / numberprizes 
cumprizenumber <- cumsum(prizenumber0) 
 
findprize <- function(n){
    prizevalue[which.max(n <= cumprizenumber)]
    }

simprizeswon <- function(bonds){
    rhyper(1, numberprizes, totalbonds - numberprizes, bonds)
    }

simprizetotal <- function(bonds){
    prizes <- simprizeswon(bonds)
    n <- sample(numberprizes, prizes)
    prizetotal <- 0
    if (prizes > 0){
        for (m in 1:prizes){
            prizetotal <- prizetotal + findprize(n[m])
            }
        }
    prizetotal
    }
```

So a simulation with the maximum £50,000 worth of bonds run 10,000 times might produce something like

```
set.seed(2023)
sims <- replicate(10^4, simprizetotal(50000)) 
table(sims)
#sims
#    0    25    50    75   100   125   150   175   200   225   250   275   300 
# 1183  1381  1389   865  1184   988   737   543   512   322   240   153   120 
#  325   350   375   400   425   450   475   500   525   550   575   600   625 
#   76    48    24    12     3     7     1    24    17    17    18    13    13 
#  650   675   700   725   750   775   800   825   850  1000  1025  1050  1075 
#   13     7    10     7     3     1     1     2     1    14     6    11     4 
# 1100  1125  1150  1175  1200  1250  1275  1300  1625  5025  5150  5175  5200 
#    7     3     5     1     1     3     2     1     1     2     1     1     1 
#10025 
#    1
```

or alternatively we could calculate the probabilities up to some point by assuming replacement (i.e. a multinomial calculation) which I doubt has much substantial error below an improbable £100,000 of prizes or more

```
multinomialprobs <- function(bonds, maxtoconsider){
  probs <- c(1,rep(0, maxtoconsider))
  for (n in 1:bonds){
    newprobs <- probs * (1 - 1/onein)
    for (p in 1:length(prizevalue)){
      if (prizevalue[p] < maxtoconsider){
        newprobs[(prizevalue[p]+1):maxtoconsider] <-  
           newprobs[(prizevalue[p]+1):maxtoconsider] + 
            probs[1:(maxtoconsider - prizevalue[p])] * 
             prizenumber[p] / totalbonds
        }
      }
    probs <- newprobs
    probs[maxtoconsider + 1] <- 1 - sum(probs[1:maxtoconsider])
    }
  names(probs) <- c(0:(maxtoconsider-1), paste0(maxtoconsider,"+"))
  probs[probs>0] 
  }
```

which for £50,000 worth of bonds and looking for prizes up to £1,500 would give

```
multinomialprobs(50000, maxtoconsider=1500) 
#            0           25           50           75          100          125 
# 1.245091e-01 1.361813e-01 1.347852e-01 9.311575e-02 1.184171e-01 9.671655e-02 
#          150          175          200          225          250          275 
# 8.027525e-02 5.170079e-02 4.546863e-02 3.191145e-02 2.344818e-02 1.424795e-02 
#          300          325          350          375          400          425 
# 1.053268e-02 6.703753e-03 4.497472e-03 2.601141e-03 1.725488e-03 1.023220e-03 
#          450          475          500          525          550          575 
# 6.391078e-04 3.541868e-04 2.085168e-03 2.164808e-03 2.093707e-03 1.435114e-03 
#          600          625          650          675          700          725 
# 1.798456e-03 1.462643e-03 1.210789e-03 7.789375e-04 6.839094e-04 4.796347e-04 
#          750          775          800          825          850          875 
# 3.522350e-04 2.139719e-04 1.581211e-04 1.006197e-04 6.749362e-05 3.903167e-05 
#          900          925          950          975         1000         1025 
# 2.588922e-05 1.535131e-05 9.587915e-06 5.313299e-06 6.398365e-04 6.980673e-04 
#         1050         1075         1100         1125         1150         1175 
# 6.901696e-04 4.766241e-04 6.057375e-04 4.946338e-04 4.104976e-04 2.643623e-04 
#         1200         1225         1250         1275         1300         1325 
# 2.324789e-04 1.631549e-04 1.198808e-04 7.284221e-05 5.384714e-05 3.427162e-05 
#         1350         1375         1400         1425         1450         1475 
# 2.299217e-05 1.329748e-05 8.820936e-06 5.230791e-06 3.267151e-06 1.810601e-06 
#        1500+ 
# 9.531394e-04
```

and, allowing for inherent simulation noise, the simulation was close to these.

There are probably faster ways of doing both the simulation and the probability calculation.